# Fatal error ao criar um novo módulo Zend Skeleton Application

Tags: zend, zend-framework-2

Estou tentando criar um módulo "Livraria" dentro de meu Zend Skeleton Application, porém dá um erro muito grande que não sei como lidar:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Zend\ModuleManager\Exception\RuntimeException' with message 'Module (Livraria) could not be initialized.' in C:\xampp\htdocs\zf2-tutorial\vendor\zendframework\zend-modulemanager\src\ModuleManager.php:203 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\zf2-tutorial\vendor\zendframework\zend-modulemanager\src\ModuleManager.php(175): Zend\ModuleManager\ModuleManager->loadModuleByName(Object(Zend\ModuleManager\ModuleEvent)) #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\zf2-tutorial\vendor\zendframework\zend-modulemanager\src\ModuleManager.php(97): Zend\ModuleManager\ModuleManager->loadModule('Livraria') #2 C:\xampp\htdocs\zf2-tutorial\vendor\zendframework\zend-eventmanager\src\EventManager.php(271): Zend\ModuleManager\ModuleManager->onLoadModules(Object(Zend\ModuleManager\ModuleEvent)) #3 C:\xampp\htdocs\zf2-tutorial\vendor\zendframework\zend-eventmanager\src\EventManager.php(143): Zend\EventManager\EventManager->triggerListeners(Object(Zend\ModuleManager\ModuleEvent)) #4 C:\xampp\htdocs\zf2-tutorial\vendor\zendframework\zend-moduleman in C:\xampp\htdocs\zf2-tutorial\vendor\zendframework\zend-modulemanager\src\ModuleManager.php on line 203

**Obs:** Se eu não adiciono 'Livraria' no arquivo **modules.config.php** a página abre normalmente, porém dá um erro **APENAS** na pagina localhost/livraria (a página localhost/application abre normalmente). O seguinte erro aparece:

> A 404 error occurred
>   Page not found.
>   The requested URL could not be matched by routing.
>   No Exception available

Configuração do **module.config.php**:

```
namespace Livraria;

use Zend\Router\Http\Literal;
use Zend\Router\Http\Segment;
use Zend\ServiceManager\Factory\InvokableFactory;

return [
    'router' => [
        'routes' => [
            'livrariahome' => [
                'type' => Literal::class,
                'options' => [
                    'route'    => '/livraria',
                    'defaults' => [
                        'controller' => Controller\IndexController::class,
                        'action'     => 'index',
                    ],
                ],
            ],
            'application' => [
                'type'    => Segment::class,
                'options' => [
                    'route'    => '/livraria[/:action]',
                    'defaults' => [
                        'controller' => Controller\IndexController::class,
                        'action'     => 'index',
                    ],
                ],
            ],
        ],
    ],
    'controllers' => [
        'factories' => [
            Controller\IndexController::class => InvokableFactory::class,
        ],
    ],
    'view_manager' => [
        'display_not_found_reason' => true,
        'display_exceptions'       => true,
        'doctype'                  => 'HTML5',
        'not_found_template'       => 'error/404',
        'exception_template'       => 'error/index',
        'template_map' => [
            'layout/layout'           => __DIR__ . '/../view/layout/layout.phtml',
            'livraria/index/index' => __DIR__ . '/../view/livraria/index/index.phtml',
            'error/404'               => __DIR__ . '/../view/error/404.phtml',
            'error/index'             => __DIR__ . '/../view/error/index.phtml',
        ],
        'template_path_stack' => [
            __DIR__ . '/../view',
        ],
    ],
];
```

Configuração do **Module.php**:

```
namespace Livraria;

class Module
{
    const VERSION = '3.0.2dev';

    public function getConfig()
    {
        return include __DIR__ . '/../config/module.config.php';
    }
}
```

Configuração do **modules.config.php**:

```
return [
    'Zend\Router',
    'Zend\Validator',
    'Application',
    'Livraria',
];
```

Configuração do **IndexController.php**:

```
namespace Livraria\Controller;

use Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController;
use Zend\View\Model\ViewModel;

class IndexController extends AbstractActionController
{
    public function indexAction()
    {
        $nome = 'Olá Livraria';
        return new ViewModel(array('nome' => $nome));
    }
}
```

Caminhos das **pastas**:

```
module/
  Livraria/
     config/
        module.config.php
     src/
        Controller/
            IndexController.php
        Module.php
     view/
        error/
            404.php
            index.phtml
        layout/
            layout.phtml
        livraria/
            index/
               index.phtml
```

Agradeço desde já a ajuda, e eu precisava muito da solução.

Answer (score 0):

Creio que o problema esteja na sua pasta "src". O correto seria ter uma pasta com o nome do módulo e, ai sim, ter a pasta controller e o arquivo Module.php, exemplificado abaixo.

```
module/
      Livraria/
         config/
            module.config.php
         src/
            Livraria/
                Controller/
                     IndexController.php
                Module.php
         view/
            error/
                404.php
                index.phtml
            layout/
                layout.phtml
            livraria/
                index/
                   index.phtml
```

Answer (score 0):

Seu arquivo Module.php está no local errado, ele precisa ficar na raiz da pasta do seu módulo:

```
module/
    Livraria/
        config/
            module.config.php
        src/
            Livraria/
                Controller/
                    IndexController.php        
        view/
            error/
                404.php
                index.phtml
            layout/
                layout.phtml
            livraria/
                index/
                    index.phtml
        Module.php
```